# Getting 301 with cURL despite FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting a 301 error, despite using FOLLOWLOCATION and MAXREDIRS.
I have no idea what to do, I tried everything I could: HEADER to 0, FOLLOWLOCATION to 1, MAXREDIRS to 30, changed USERAGENT multiple times, used COOKIEFILE alone, then COOKIEJAR along with it, but nothing.

Here's the weirdest part: the same website I'm trying to scrape doesn't give 301 for other pages, just for certain ones. Any ideas??

```
function curl_start($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $html;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code? As followlocation should work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1`? It should be obvious from there what it's trying to do. Don't keep us guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work unless you are running php in safe mode. But even that is not an issue in your case.

Anyway, try this.

```
<?php
function curl_redirect_exec($ch, &$redirects, $curlopt_header = false) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(array_pop($matches));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        if (isset($url_parsed)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $redirects++;
            return curl_redirect_exec($ch, $redirects);
        }
    }
    if ($curlopt_header)
        return $data;
    else {
        list(,$body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        return $body;
    }
}
?>
```

SRC: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#95027

Comment: I tried it, but the function didn't work. I tried fixing it, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my server. So I guess it has something to do with `safe_mode` or an `open_basedir` is set. You could check for an output warning by starting your script with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It should show a warning.

Check the following link to see a solution.

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php#102121

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm still working on this, but you've provided me with a great insight. I'm a bit confused since I just wrote a small php script that runs separately from the entire system and it scraps a page without any problem, but when I incorporate its code in the CMS, it doesn't work. Weird, but I'll keep trying. Thanks once more.