# php cURL function 301 error

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I am using this code :

```
function getUrl($url) {
if(@function_exists('curl_init')) {
    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CrawlBot/1.0.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 15);            
    $site = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    } else {
    global $site;
    $site = file_get_contents($url);
}
return $site;
};
```

But i see error 301 Moved Permanently.

What can i do to solve this ? *can you give me the correct code please ?*

Comment: Looks like the server does not provide WHERE the location moved to, so your curl does not have any url to FOLLOWLOCATION. You can't do anything and your code is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054652/getting-301-with-curl-despite-followlocation have you seen this ?

Comment: @kk12391 yes, how should i change My code ?

Comment: This [`link`](http://slopjong.de/2012/03/31/curl-follow-locations-with-safe_mode-enabled-or-open_basedir-set/) will be helpful.

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects/3520085#3520085` go through this

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thanks , and what code should i use instead of my code ?

Comment: @kk12391 thanks, but i can't modify my code :( can you do it for me please ?

Comment: Try that yourself if you want to learn something. ;) :P

Comment: @kk12391 okay :D but i am beginner !   is there anyone to do it please ? :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` cannot be activated when in `safe_mode` or an
>   `open_basedir` is set

You may try this:

**Solution 1:**

Set `safe_mode = Off` in your `php.ini` file (it's usually in `/etc/` on the server). If that's already off, then look around for the `open_basedir` stuff in the `php.ini` file and comment that line (#open_basedir...). Restart apache server.

**Solution 2:**
If the above doesn't work (it should!) try this:

```
<?php
function geturl($url){

(function_exists('curl_init')) ? '' : die('cURL Must be installed for geturl function to work. Ask your host to enable it or uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini');

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CrawlBot/1.0.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 15);     

$html = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($status['http_code']!=200){
    if($status['http_code'] == 301 || $status['http_code'] == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $html, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match("/(Location:|URI:)[^(\n)]*/", $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(str_replace($matches[1],"",$matches[0]));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        return (isset($url_parsed))? geturl($url):'';
    }
}
return $html;
}

?>
```

Comment: i replaced the code . and i opened my php file (crawler.php) and then i see white page :)

Comment: add this code to the top of your script, then past the errors here. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 7):

You might need to enable follow redirects using the location header flag:

`curl -L <URL>`