# How to scrape a webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage and parse some data from it. But everytime I try to scrape I get only the **http response header**. Here is my code that I used to get the data from the website..

```
$host = 'Host: dealnews.com';
$user_agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0';
$accept = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$accept_language = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$accept_encoding = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$connection = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$cookie = 'Cookie=front_page_sort=hotness; dnvta=%7B%22uid%22%3A%22VkA1VlBBb0tNcXdBQVF6UlJrTUFBQUJN%22%2C%22vid%22%3A%22VkA1bGx3b0tNcXdBQVF6bW53QUFBQUEt%22%2C%22fvts%22%3A1475237180%2C%22lvts%22%3A1475241453%2C%22ref%22%3A%22%22%2C%22usid%22%3A0%2C%22ct%22%3A2%2C%22cr%22%3A1475237180%7D; last_visit=1475241457; _ceg.s=oebjle; _ceg.u=oebjle; _ga=GA1.2.185245695.1475237222; __gads=ID=1921ec3c3fe54b1b:T=1475237222:S=ALNI_MZJZEuNpmg3Aq5e007E7iFjwuQ0nw; original_eref=DIRECT; _gat=1; mp_dealnews_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%221577afe52c549-01b1cfdcc8ca548-13666c4a-100200-1577afe52c620c%22%7D';

$requestHeaders = array ( $host, $user_agent, $accept, $accept_encoding, $accept_language, $connection, $cookie );

$ch = curl_init ( 'http://dealnews.com/2-LED-Window-Candles-w-Color-Changing-Bulbs-for-4-2-s-h/1797165.html?iref=rss-dealnews-todays-edition' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders );
$data = curl_exec ( $ch );
if (! $data) {
    die ( "Error: " . curl_error ( $ch ) . " Error no: " . curl_errno ( $ch ) );
}
curl_close ( $ch );
$htmlContent = str_get_html ( $data );
echo $htmlContent;
```

But it gives me the error as given below..

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2016 13:50:44 GMT Server: Apache X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 Status: 302 Found Location: /lw/landing.html?uri=%2F2-LED-Window-Candles-w-Color-Changing-Bulbs-for-4-2-s-h%2F1797165.html%3Firef%3Drss-dealnews-todays-edition Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 20 X-Cnection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

so can someone help me out with where I am going wrong in this

Comment: That's a redirect. Enable the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

Comment: oh yea! Thank you @Barmar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does this debug-verbose-info mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533450/what-does-this-debug-verbose-info-mean)

Comment: I always get this feeling that it's somehow unethical to answer questions about website scraping or similar ... :\

Comment: @CD001 Im doing the scraping work for the same client whose website I will be scraping. So with their permission only I am scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

The header `302` is a redirect information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to ScreenScrape using PHP, I have successfully done it using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) libarary. It's very straight forward and easy to use. I know the site looks a bit antiquated, but my code from last year is still running strong. Haven't had a CRON error yet.